# What does "an eater of broken meats" mean from this Shakespeare play?

Tags: meaning, archaicisms, shakespeare

In the clip below from *King Lear*, what does "an eater of broken meats" mean, what does he mean by that. I know it is derogatory and is most likely meant to refer to an awful person. Literally, would this imply someone who eats rotten meat?

> A knave; a rascal; an eater of broken meats; a
> base, proud, shallow, beggarly, three-suited,
> hundred-pound, filthy, worsted-stocking knave; a
> lily-livered, action-taking knave, a whoreson,
> glass-gazing, super-serviceable finical rogue;
> one-trunk-inheriting slave; one that wouldst be a
> bawd, in way of good service, and art nothing but
> the composition of a knave, beggar, coward, pandar,
> and the son and heir of a mongrel bitch: one whom I
> will beat into clamorous whining, if thou deniest
> the least syllable of thy addition.
>
> ― William Shakespeare, King Lear

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Broken meats* refers to the leftovers from a rich people's meal, which were eaten by the servants or given to the poor. ('Meat' in the sense 'food', not just flesh.) In Renaissance times a 'course' would consist of a selection of dishes, like a buffet, and diners weren't expected to have some of everything, so there would be lots left over.
See [this](https://readable.com/blog/greatest-insults-shakespeare/#:%7E:text=An%20eater%20of%20broken%20meats.,leftovers%20from%20someone%20else%27s%20feast.%60)

Comment: Thanks for the useful information and link.

Comment: Kate Bunting - With the above answer in mind, would it be correct to infer that "broken" means a past tense form of "break" as in to "to break bread"?

Comment: Yes, I expect so; e.g. pies and cakes that had had slices cut out.